# How to work with COCO object detection datasets in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, dataset

I'm super new to this topic of object detection and TensorFlow and I was wondering how can I load [this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSd00.png) as a TensorFlow dataset? I've used pandas to read it as a DataFrame but I can't parse it to a TensorFlow dataset. I've tried this

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
  (
    tf.cast(dataframe['file'].values, tf.string),
    tf.cast(dataframe['width'].values, tf.int8),
    tf.cast(dataframe['height'].values, tf.int8)
  ),
  (
    # tf.cast(dataframe['annotations'].values, tf.string)
    # here I want to cast the annotations to the dataset but I don't 
    # know how
  )
)
```

but could not figure out how to get the annotations to work here... Any help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your data is in JSON format,
Directly use `tf.io.decode_json_example` library to read the json values.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.io.decode_json_example([
    [example_json, example_json],
    [example_json, example_json]]).shape.as_list()
```

For more details on the library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_json_example?version=nightly).